# Update all branches of local to align with remote

Tags: git

I was working on Computer A which created new branches on remote.

I moved over to Computer B and need to figure out how to update my local repo to get all the new branches, as well as changes to branches it already had that may have had new commits.

Is this something I can do with the git command line?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to proceed for each branch successively, since automating this is made impractical by the fact that `pull` *can* result in conflicts, which would need to be resolved manually.

**1) Getting all your remote-tracking branches up-to-date with the remote**

```
git fetch
```

After this step, you can already see in the output the names of the new or updated branches.

---

**2) Updating local branches**

*(note : do not use the name of the remote-tracking branch here, but the name of the branch itself. i.e.* `master` *not* `origin/master` *)*

```
git checkout <branchName>
```

If this is a new branch to your local, you can stop here, you have an up-to-date copy now. But if you already had a copy of this branch locally, you'll now have to do

```
git pull
```

which merges `origin/<branchName>` into `<branchName>`.

Resolve conflicts if any, but many branches might result in fast-forward merges, specifically those which *you* didn't modify recently enough.

---

And finally, yes it can be a bit long if you have many branches, but you only need to update branches you want to work on *now*, no need to frantically update *every local* branch after each `fetch`.

Comment: I approve (and up'ed). I'll however add the suggestion to run `git pull --rebase`, in case the local branch and its remote diverged, to avoid to have a merge commit. This would end up in a cleaner and easier to read history/log.

Comment: @padawin I tend to forget to mention the possibility, as I myself rarely use it, but you're right, it's a useful addition.